# How to get a snapshot of few bytes at various point of a device?

Tags: hard-disk

I have a device that I'm not sure anymore whether I filled it with random bits few month ago. I'd like to get 10 bytes at 10 different places of that device. Is it possible to do so in bash ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

`dd if=/dev/device of=output-file bs=1 count=10 skip=<offset of data>`

It does exactly what it says on the tin; read 10 bytes starting from the given position on the device to output-file. It also works for regular files as well (and even pipes). If you want standard output, just omit the `of=` part.

Note that the status information is written to stderr (not stdout), so it won't interfere with pipes or redirection; if you wish to suppress it, add `status=none` on Linux, or `2>/dev/null`).

Comment: nice how do I do to make it print the output directly in the terminal rather than in a file ?

Comment: also how would I see the binaries (0 & 1) rather than the system trying to interpret the stream into characters ?

Comment: Remove the `of=output-file` option; now it'll go to stdout.  You might then want to pipe that through `od -cx` or `xxd` or `hexdump` or similar to get a readable dump with no risk of control-characters messing the screen up.

Comment: @StephenHarris just out of curiosity is there an equivalent of xxd or hexdump or od that displays the raw binaries ?

Comment: What do you mean by "raw binaries"?  That _would_ be the stdout from `dd` and it's likely not what you want 'cos it may contain characters that mess with your screen.  Typically when looking at binary data you want to use something to convert binary data into hex (or similar) for ease of viewing.

Comment: @ChiseledAbs Do you perhaps want `strings`? It will only print printable characters.